# PyQt5's PyQt5.sip File is Not Generated by the SIP Library

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-sip

I'm building SIP 4.19.12 and PyQt 5.11.2 on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017. I'm planning to do that for Python x86 2.7.15.
I downloaded the versions above and extracted them, installed enum34 with pip, the configured SIP with

```
python configure.py --sip-module PyQt5.sip --no-tools
```

This is SIP 4.19.12 for Python 2.7.15 on win32.

> The PyQt5.sip module will be installed in
>
> C:\Users\FiFo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5.
>
> The sip.pyi stub file will be installed in
>
> C:\Users\FiFo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5.
>
> The default directory to install .sip files in is
>
> C:\Users\FiFo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\sip. Creating
>
> sipconfig.py... Creating top level Makefile... Creating sip code
>
> generator Makefile... Creating sip module Makefile...

Setup the x86 building environment with

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86
```

Followed by nmake:

> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.15.26729.0
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> ```
>     cd siplib
>     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe
> ```
>
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.15.26729.0
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> ```
>     cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -O2 -MD -W3 -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DSIP_MODULE_NAME=\"PyQt5.sip\" -I. -IC:\Users\FiFo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\include -Fo @C:\Users\FiFo\AppData\Local\Temp\nm8C0F.tmp siplib.c apiversions.c
> ```
>
> descriptors.c qtlib.c threads.c objmap.c voidptr.c array.c
>
> int_convertors.c Generating Code...
>
> ```
>     cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -O2 -MD -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DSIP_MODULE_NAME=\"PyQt5.sip\" -I. -IC:\Users\FiFo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\include -Fo @C:\Users\FiFo\AppData\Local\Temp\nm9111.tmp bool.cpp
>
>     link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DLL /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:sip.pyd.manifest /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /INCREMENTAL:NO
> ```
>
> /OUT:sip.pyd @C:\Users\FiFo\AppData\Local\Temp\nm9170.tmp    Creating
>
> library sip.lib and object sip.exp
>
> ```
>     mt -nologo -manifest sip.pyd.manifest -outputresource:sip.pyd;2
> ```

Then installed the packages with nmake install:

> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.15.26729.0
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> ```
>     cd siplib
>     "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"
> ```
>
> install
>
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.15.26729.0
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> ```
>     copy /y sip.pyd C:\Users\FiFo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\sip.pyd
>     1 file(s) copied.
>     copy /y D:\opencv\sip-4.19.12\sip.pyi C:\Users\FiFo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\sip.pyi
>     1 file(s) copied.
>     C:\Users\FiFo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\python.exe
> ```
>
> D:\opencv\sip-4.19.12\mk_distinfo.py ""
>   C:\Users\FiFo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5_sip-4.19.12.dist-info
>   installed.txt
>
> D:\opencv\sip-4.19.12\sipgen>pip freeze
>
> backports.functools-lru-cache==1.5 cycler==0.10.0 enum34==1.1.6
>   kiwisolver==1.0.1 matplotlib==2.2.3 numpy==1.15.1 Pillow==5.2.0
>   pynaoqi==2.1.4.13 pyparsing==2.2.0 PyQt5-sip==4.19.12
>   python-dateutil==2.7.3 pytz==2018.5 six==1.11.0

But I cannot find that PyQt5.sip file anywhere. Building PyQt gives:

> D:\opencv\PyQt5_gpl-5.11.2>python configure.py Querying qmake about
>   your Qt installation... Error: Unable to import PyQt5.sip. Make sure
>   you have configured SIP to create a private copy of the sip module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug with the stable version. The authors suggested downloading the latest snapshot which worked. Another solution would be:

"to create an empty __ init__.py file in the same directory containing sip.pyd."

After that I configured with:

```
python configure.py --qmake d:\qt5_32\bin\qmake.exe --static --sip-incdir ..\sip-4.19.13.dev1809111822\siplib --sip d:\opencv\sip-4.19.13.dev1809111822\sipgen\sip.exe --confirm-license
```

Comment: I confirm that creating an empty `__init__.py` file worked for me. I have also created a gist that go through the all process (https://gist.github.com/rllola/da97b890a79d206f00a909bc2a56598d). I hope this might help.